Multiple loops in JMeter load testing configuration
I have 34 accounts and I need each of them to log in 1 time only and perform creation of 10 accounts per user logged in. That makes of a total of 340 accounts to be created. However, I think I set up my configuration incorrectly. The script either stops right away or throws "Error occured compiling the tree: - see log file".
The following is my JMeter configuration
Thread: 34
Ramp-up: 1
Loop Counts: 1
Duration: 180
Loop Controller: 10

So what does jmeter.log file say? We cannot help you without seeing it. If there are no suspicious entries you can try increasing JMeter logging verbosity to debug level.
Your configuration seems to be correct, by the way.
The most common reason for Error occured compiling the tree is that your test is using a JMeter Plugin and the plugin is not installed in your JMeter instance, try adding JMeter Plugins Manager and it should detect and suggest you to install the plugin(s) used in your script.
